# How can I have setuptools compile mixed C and C++ for use with Cython?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I have a C++ project that I'm adapting to be usable from Python. Its dependencies are all vendored C libraries, so the build needs to happen in at least 2 parts, one for the C sources and one for the Cython & C++ sources. I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to do this through setuptools in my `setup.py` though.

I can see that distutils exposes a way to manually invoke the compiler, but when you ask it for the compiler, it picks a default based on `os.name` instead of resolving which one the `setup()` function is going to use.